# What's the purpose of using JQuery toggle() within filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search input field and a table. As you type in some words, the table shows the row that matches the words you typed. I saw an example on W3School. They use JQuery toggle() within filter(), which I don't really understand. The code like this

html

```
<input class='form-control' id='myInput' type='text' placeholder='Search.....'>
<table>
    <thead>
       table header......
    </thead>
    <tbody id='myTable'>
        here goes 4 rows
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myInput').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#myTable tr').filter(function(){
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
});
});
```

Anyone could explain the line of code within the filter() function? What's the purpose of that and how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really an improper use of filter which is typically used to reduce a collection based on criteria in the callback. They are using it simply to create a loop that isolates each instance of `<tr>` and not providing any criteria to actually do any filtering

A more appropriate and easier to understand way would be replace `filter` with `each` to do exactly the same thing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes a lot more sense to use each instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
```

The Above code hide and show the table rows based on the input value user enter in the input field.

jquery toggle() function hide and show the html elements.

indexOf(value) function used to search the string for given value.

Comment: Thanks. What I am confused about is why they put toggle() within the filter();